# How can I color different sentences differently in a textarea control using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textarea

I need to be able to programmatically (vb.net) define the color of different sentences in a textarea.  I can do this with a richtextbox in a forms application but I need to be able to do it in a web application and I do not need the full functionality of most aftermarket asp.net richtext editors, just a simple display of different colored text.

I have tried a textbox control and it can only have one color of the text.  I have tried a textarea control and can't figure out how to change the text color programmatically using vb.net.

Vb.net

```
Dim Sentence1 as string="This is what I have tried"

TextArea1.Value = Sentence1 & "Test Color"
```

I need Sentence1 to be in blue and "Test Color" to be in red but there is no property that I can find to set this.  I have tried TextArea1.Forecolor, TextArea1.Color, TextArea1.Style, etc. but nothing seems to be available to set the text color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vb.net using a richtextbox:

```
With RichTextBox1
        .SelectionColor = Color.Green
        .AppendText("hello ")
        .SelectionColor = Color.Red
        .AppendText("world")
End With
```

EDIT:
for your case which is asp and textarea, this is not my code btw:

Suppose, you have following layout at aspx

```
<div id="textarea">
<%=txt%>
</div>
```

Then in the code-behind define txt as

```
Protected txt As String

txt = "I look like textarea
<span style=""color:red"">some red text here</span>
<span style=""color:orange"">I have a basket of oranges</span>"
```

This should print the required text in red and orange.

Try this too: `txtdiv.innerhtml="Some normal text <span style='color: red;'>some red text</span>`

Comment: Yes.  I can do that in a forms application but I am working with a web application and the richtextbox is not available in web apps.  I need to be able to do it either in a textarea (which should be possible) or a textbox (which I do not think is possible).  I don't want to have to use an aftermarket richtextbox for asp.net because I do not need that much functionality.

Comment: The first way you presented did not work.  In fact nothing works with a textarea.  It appears that the text color attribute is locked down. However, the last way you presented did work with a div instead of a label.  This is what I ended up with:TxtDiv.InnerHtml = "<span style='color:#FF0000'> One </span><span style='color:#0000FF'> Two </span><span style='color:#FFA500'> Three </span><span style='color:#008000'> Four </span><span style='color:#800080'> Five </span>"  Thanks

Comment: First way is for vb.net and it works, second way was answered on another forum which was marked as answer, last way is too common and everyone is using it, if you see i helped tick the answer. I changed label to txtdiv.innerhtml